# How to do the newest FB UIView animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, animation

in the newest FB client one animation is like
[image]

This is the normal FB check in page and if click left-top corner button, the preference page show with an left to right animation:

[image]

How to make it? I know the way to do UIView left to right animation, but not like this, part of checkin page still in screen, and if click left-top corner button, check in button back to original position...

Comment: Maybe this is a start https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView

Comment: No, man, you gave me the original iPad view sample, what I want is from iPhone, and it is an animation, as the screenshot shows, when you click left-top button, the first view will do a animation from left to right and stop the position like second shot shows.

Comment: @Mattias Wadman but I think your sample can help me some in the future, so thank you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just open-sourced a project on Github which accomplishes exactly what you're looking for in a manner that resembles Facebook's implementation most accurately.

Check it out at Github: https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController